# Java Programming For Android App Won't Load

Tags: java, android

I've just been making an android app using the android developer kit and I created a layout with a medium text and 1 button

it is meant to show some text in a dialogue when you click the button but when I run the app on my device to test it freezes and doesn't show the button or text I added then my whole device freezes.

I can't figure out what I've don't wrong I'm am a complete noob at this so I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Success!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Some Text Here.");
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is anything in the logcat, that would be helpful. But I believe your problem is here

```
 Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

Assuming you have a `Button` in your `activity_main.xml` with `androidid="@+id/button1"`, this line should be

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

When you use the namespace `android.R.someReference` you are telling it to look for a pre-defined Android `resource`. But here the `resource` is one that you have declared yourself so you leave off the `android.`

Comment: You are welcome...we all started somewhere. You can thank me by clicking the checkmark next to the answer in 6 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the button you are referring to the android resources, and that doesn't have your button. Remove the `android.` and it will work!